# Error in running or configuring grails application with asynchrounous mail plugin throws exceptions

Tags: spring, email, grails, asynchronous, grails-2.3

i want to integrated grails **asynchronous-mail:1.0** plugin to my app for that i have added following to my build config
**compile ":asynchronous-mail:1.0"**

after that as i tried to run-app which fails by following exceptions

```
| Error 2014-06-26 11:49:55,958 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'nonAsynchronousMailService': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'grailsApplication' of bean class [grails.plugin.mail.MailService]: Bean property 'grailsApplication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Message: Error creating bean with name 'nonAsynchronousMailService': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'grailsApplication' of bean class [grails.plugin.mail.MailService]: Bean property 'grailsApplication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
```

---

```
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'grailsApplication' of bean class [grails.plugin.mail.MailService]: Bean property 'grailsApplication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
```

---

```
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

if i remove 
compile ":asynchronous-mail:1.0"
from build-config.groovy 
application runs well
is there any trouble with  grails version 2.3.9  or with asynchronous-mail plugin

features in asynchronous-mail plugin are seems to realy good and want to use it

i am using following plugin also they are working fine

```
    build ":tomcat:7.0.53"
    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
    compile ':cache:1.1.2'         
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.15" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.2"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.8"     

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
    runtime ":email-confirmation:2.0.8"

    provided ":codenarc:0.21"

    compile (":postgresql-extensions:0.9.0") {
        excludes "hibernate"
    }

    compile ":browser-detection:0.4.3"
```

Anybody who is facing this problem please help 
thanks in advance

Comment: [plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail) say it was migrated to the quartz plugin.Also it depends on hibernate, quartz and mail plugins. Stop server, include remaining dependencies, then refresh your dependencies from IDE then try by doing grails clean.

Comment: hi swapnil i am using email-confirmation also which in turns depends on quartz plugin and mail do i need to config them separately too?

Comment: For time being please remove email-confirmation, refresh, clean and then try  this plugins configuring them separately. Make this work first and then go to email-confirmation.

Comment: hi Swapnil thanks reordering email-confirmation after asynchronous one and then refresh dependencies had worked for me.

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. so I will post it as an answer for you to accept as further readers will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plugin docs](http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail) say it was migrated to the quartz plugin.Also it depends on hibernate, quartz and mail plugins. Stop server, include remaining dependencies, then refresh your dependencies from IDE then try by doing grails clean.

For time being please remove email-confirmation, refresh, clean and then try this plugins configuring them separately. Make asynchronous-mail work first and then go to email-confirmation.
i.e. reordering email-confirmation after asynchronous one.

Comment: The plugin does not need to include additional dependencies. It contains all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Which version on JDK you are using?

Try upgrading your quartz, mail & spring security core plugin.

```
compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
compile ":mail:1.0.5", {
    excludes 'spring-test'
}
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
```

Restart your grails plugin after clean.

Comment: hi thanks for quick reply i am usingquartz, mail & spring security core plugin are all upto their latest version and as per JDK i am using oracle jdk7

Comment: Okay, after looking at your buildconfig (posted in the issue), I thought, you were using an older version of those 3 plugins. I'll get back to you for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just exclude dependencies on mail and quartz of email-confirmation

```
runtime ":email-confirmation:2.0.8" {
    excludes 'mail', 'quartz'
}
```

Try to use latest Release Candidate `:asynchronous-mail:1.1-RC1`.